# Prevent Gmail from assigning a category when the message has a user-defined label (Multiple Inboxes enabled)

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-categories

I appreciate the organization that comes with Gmail automatically assigning my messages to categories. However, I have one source of email that is a veritable firehose, and Gmail seems to think they should be placed in the "Updates" category. I already have a filter set up to skip the Inbox and apply a label, but the Updates category is rendered useless.

I tried editing the filter, but the only option I could see relating to categories was choosing a category to assign, and "None" wasn't an option.

I also manually removed them by selecting them and choosing `Not "Updates"`, but it seems Gmail does not learn from actions like this.

Is there any way to remove these from the Updates category? I am using Multiple Inboxes so dragging messages out of the category doesn't offer the option to always do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly from [GMail's help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3055016?hl=en):

> **Move messages between tabs**
>
> [image: move message between tabs]
>
> If you see a message in your inbox that you want in a different tab, all you have to do is drag and drop it into the other tab. Another way to do this is to right-click a message while viewing your inbox.
>
> **After you move a message to a different tab, a message above your inbox will ask if you want to undo that action or choose to always put messages from that sender in the tab you chose.**

If you drag and drop the message to the tab you want the message in, it should prompt you and confirm if Gmail should always move messages from that sender to the inbox category of your choice.

When I do this with a message, I receive the following prompt at the top of the screen:

[image: confirm future moves]

Comment: I'm using Multiple Inboxes, so I don't actually have this view. Clicking on the Updates category (in the left-side menu) shows the messages, and if I then drag the message to the label I've given it, it says the conversation has been moved and no longer displays it in Updates, but does not give me the choice to always apply that action.

Comment: I'll try leaving Multiple Inboxes and applying this.

Comment: Thanks, I had to re-enable the tabs, drag the message to "Primary" and use that option. Now it seems to be working.

Comment: I'm sorry @WinnieNicklaus I don't see how this answers your original post.  You said you wanted **NO** category, thenn phantoms says, 'here's how you change form one category to another'.  That's not answering the question.  It certainly doesn't help me.  I need **NO** category because I want custom IMAP folders to receive these and not have them in primary, social, promotion, forum OR update.

Answer (score 4):

The correct category to assign via a filter, would be "Personal".

[image: (partial) screenshot of choosing a category]

Comment: This option was removed as of Sep-2019